# Selenium IDE, issue accessing to frames

Tags: selenium, frame

im working with Selenium IDE for the generation of test cases on a web containing frames.
I’m in a web page with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mantenci&oacute;n de Productos</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<frameset rows="224,120,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" cols="*">
    <frame name="arriba" scrolling="NO" src="x.enc.adm.fbusprod.jsp" >
    <frame name="centro" scrolling="auto" src="x.enc.adm.blanco.jsp">
    <frame name="abajo" scrolling="AUTO" src="x.enc.adm.datoprod.jsp">
    <frame>
</frameset>
<noframes>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
</body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

I need to select an ítem that is inside of the “arriba” frame, so if I search this item, Selenium can’t fint it, so I’m using:

Command: selectFrame - Target: arriba

For which  I’m getting:
[error] Element arriba not found

Also i’ve using:

1 Command: selectFrame - Target: relative-top

2 Command: selectFrame - Target: arriba

But i’m still getting:
[error] Element arriba not found

Somebody could help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this in the past:

1. Command: waitForElementPresent - Target: arriba - Value: 3000
2. Command: waitForFrameToLoad - Target: arriba - Value: 5000
3. Command: selectFrame - Target: arriba